# local MySQL remote access

Tags: mysql, debian, local, remote-access

I'm trying to access my own (local) MySQL database from remote server

1) Is it possible if I know my IP on Debian Desktop?

2) Following some tutorials i've made change in mysql config (/etc/mysql/my.cnf): commented line to #bind-address       = 127.0.0.1

3) I've created user and gave access to everything (just to test)

4) I'm trying to access it like mysql -h -u -p getting in response: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (110)

5) in return $ netstat -ntlp |grep 3306:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you use the public IP adress of your local machine?  Are you sure it is reachable and not behind a firewall?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using my IP from http://checkip.amazonaws.com/. About firewall.. I made "$ /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT" command. but not sure its enough

Comment: Can you access MySQL from another machine in your office?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hm.. i have the same IP http://checkip.amazonaws.com for any device in my network. is problem here? I need some kind of personal IP for each device?

Comment: I am trying to ascertain whether _any_ computer can connect to your local MySQL database.  Forget about AWS for a moment.

Comment: >>Can you access MySQL from another machine in your office?
I mean that If i have few devices with same public IP, which are running mysql how do command "$ mysql -h -u -p" will decide which mysql it should run. Im not good in networks and servers. sorry